# When yarn.lock is removed dependencies are installed as CommonJS, otherwise as ES modules

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

We're having a problem on a JS project with yarn where if I remove `yarn.lock` and `yarn install` then everything works correctly and the dependencies are installed as CommonJS (and if I go to a package files I can see they use `require()` and `module.exports`), but then when we commit `yarn.lock` and the project builds somewhere else, or if I say install a new unrelated dependency, I go to the same package files and I can see that now it looks like they're installed as ES modules (I see `import` and `export default`)

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour? Our current workaround is to not include `yarn.lock` in the repo, and if we need to install a new dependency we remove the `node_modules` dir and `yarn.lock`, which isn't ideal.

This only started happening since we updated the project to use Node 18 (might we had to update all libraries at that time, so it might not be directly related to Node). We're using Yarn 1.22.19. The project is written in TypeScript, compiled to ES6 and is used as a dependency in other projects.

Comment: Have you tried installing with `--frozen-lockfile`? Seems like your package and lock files aren't in sync.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe ok so for example:
1. I delete node_modules and yarn.lock
2. run "yarn install"
3. open node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js and it says "(...) module.exports = string => typeof string  (...)"
4. I then delete only node_modules and run "yarn install --frozen-lockfile"
5. open node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js and it says "(...) export default function stripAnsi(string) (...)"

Comment: What you're describing makes no sense. `strip-ansi` went ESM in [v7](https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi/releases/tag/v7.0.0); it's very unlikely you have even a _transitive_ dependency that would permit a major version change and Yarn should follow the lockfile for a reproducible tree anyway. Can you give a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out.. we're not using strip-ansi directly, but some of our dependencies do.

On subsequent yarn installs we were getting warnings such as this one:

"warning Pattern ["strip-ansi@^6.0.1"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/pricca/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-strip-ansi-cjs-6.0.1-9e26c63d30f53443e9489495b2105d37b67a85d9-integrity/node_modules/strip-ansi-cjs" as pattern ["strip-ansi-cjs@npm:strip-ansi@^6.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.".

So I'm guessing on a fresh install one version of strip-ansi was being installed and then afterwards different ones, so in order to have a deterministic behaviour I've added the dependencies we were getting warnings about as our direct dependencies in the package.json with their latest versions.